# How change default url (remove subdirectory) for MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Just deployed ASP.NET MVC5 web application to IIS 10. To do this, under "default website", I created a new application ("Add application"). I had to put in an alias so I put in "xyz".

So, now the public url is similar to http://xyz.mysite.com/xyz .... but I want it to be only http://xyz.mysite.com (remove 'xyz' subdirectory).

How can I do this?

The problem is that my ajax calls are failing because of the subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the following:

Option 1:
 Add Website in your IIS (instead of Add Application) and use the SNI feature. All relative path will be from root (/) level.

or

Option 2:
Modify your AJAX calls to use @Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName") so your URLs will be generated properly based on relative path. I suspect you are hardcoding actionNames to "/controllerName/actionName" which uses root as your relative path.

Comment: The @Url.Action helped specifically with all the failing AJAX calls. Thanks!

Comment: How do I set it up to use SNI?

Comment: Here is a sample steps on how to setup SNI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability#create-a-secure-web-site It is the Server Name Indication field in IIS.

Comment: Is SNI the only way to remove that "/audit" alias for this web app?

Comment: If your "Default Website" is not taken, then you can just disable that and "Add Website" that points to this web application. If the "Default Website" is taken and using the default port 80, you can "Add Website" with different port and point it to this web application. You will be using something like http://xyz.mysite.com:81/ as your base URL for this web application.